# Check if values are within an absolute intervall

Tags: r

I have a data.frame with numeric values.

```
dat <- data.frame(time = c(421.95,362.91,327.98,253.98,254.28,253.97,253.98,3.22,0))
```

I would like to check which of those values are within a certain interval. For example: If the absolute range of that interval is 3, the expected output is:

```
dat <- data.frame(time = c(421.95,362.91,327.98,253.98,254.28,253.97,253.98,3.22,0), Output = c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0))
```

I tried using `dplyr`:

```
dat %>% group_by(time %in% seq(252,255,0.01))
```

But I have to specify the range [252,255], which I can not do in my data. Is there a vectorized solution to mark all values that lie within a given interval?

*Edit*

I wrote a quick (and flawed) Loop that hopefully helps to explain the Problem:

```
dat$New <- "NA"
for (i in 1:(nrow(dat)-1)) {
ifelse((dat[i,1] - dat[i+1,1]) > -2 & (dat[i,1] - dat[i+1,1]) < 2,dat[i,2] <- "1",dat[i,2] <- "0")
}
```

I need to compare all consecutive values with on another and check whether they meet the range critera.

Comment: If you are comparing the adjacent elements, `c(FALSE, abs(diff(dat$time)) < 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to get the result.  We can wrap with `+` on a logical index to convert to binary, or use `as.integer/as.numeric` or add 0 to it, or there are convenient functions like `between` in both `dplyr/data.table` to get the logical index (which can be later converted to binary).

```
 dat$output <- with(dat, +(time > 252 & time < 255))
 dat$output
 #[1] 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
as.integer(dat$time %between% c(252, 255))
```

Or

```
(dat$time %between% c(252, 255))+0L
```

Or

```
ifelse(dat$time %between% c(252, 255), 1, 0)
```

NOTE: The idea was first posted here....

#### Update

If we are comparing adjacent elements and to check if the absolute difference is less than 2, then

```
c(FALSE, abs(diff(dat$time)) < 2)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The Problem is that I do not know the range of time in my data. So the solution has to work for all expressions of time that lie within an absolute range of say 3.

Comment: @count If you don't know the range, what is the criteria for getting the range?

Comment: Its a difftime of two different Dates. Unfortunately, they all have the same key variable, so I cannot use `group_by` on the data.

Comment: It's better not to use `+()` as it is a bit hackish, but instead use `as.integer` (or `as.numeric`).

Comment: @Jaap I don't find any reason not to use `+`.   You can use `as.integer` or anything else..

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this in base R:

```
 dat$output <- (dat$time > 252 & dat$time < 255)*1
```

or:

```
 dat$output <- (dat$time > 252 & dat$time < 255) + 0L
```

or:

```
 dat$output <- as.integer(dat$time > 252 & dat$time < 255)
```

or:

```
transform(dat, output = (time > 252 & time < 255)*1)
```

All variations result in:

```
> dat
    time output
1 421.95      0
2 362.91      0
3 327.98      0
4 253.98      1
5 254.28      1
6 253.97      1
7 253.98      1
8   3.22      0
9   0.00      0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am looking for a generalized solution (I edited my original comment) to check which expressions of time -regardles of their value- lie within a certain range.

Comment: @count Was AFK for a moment, but akrun already included a solution for that as you have seen.